# asp.net mvc UnitOfWork

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Добрый день! Пытаюсь освоить азы asp.net, есть не большой вопрос.
Разбираю пример работы с UnitOfWork, вот отсюда http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.3.php .
Вопрос:
Можно ли создать универсальный UnitOfWork для любых репозиториев или надо для каждой отдельной группы резозиториев создавать свой UnitOfWork с методами типа

```
public BookRepository Books
{
    get
    {
        if (bookRepository == null)
            bookRepository = new BookRepository(db);
        return bookRepository;
    }
}
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация паттерна "Общий репозиторий" и UnityOfWork
https://habrahabr.ru/post/238737/

Answer (score 0):

Можно) Вот:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Save();
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

    T Get(Int32? id);

    IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, Boolean> predicate);

    void Create(T item);

    void Update(T item);

    void Delete(Int32 id);
}
```

Реализовать думаю интерфейсы сможете?